# ipcRenderer not receiving messages reliably on startup

Tags: reactjs, electron, ipcrenderer

I have a problem with the ipcRenderer not receiving a message from ipcMain when my app is initializing.

I’m running a 3rd party component from which I want to receive some settings. Once the variables are stored in a state variable within my home component, I’m rendering a certain div.

When logging the events, I can see that main.js is receiving the request from the ipcRenderer and when printing the settings I can see the data. However my window is not receiving the answer. Sometimes when I relaunch the app it works but right now it is not reliable and I don’t really understand why.

Main.js:

```
ipcMain.on('getSettings', () => {
    console.log('getSettings was triggered.')
    console.log(settings.store.store)
    mainWindow.webContents.send('allSettings', settings.store.store)
  });
```

Home.js:

```
   import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
   const { ipcRenderer } = electron;
    
    const Home = () => {
      const [settings, setSettings] = useState(null);
      const [startedUp, setStartedUp] = useState(false);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        ipcRenderer.on('allSettings', (event, data) => { loadSettings(data); });
    
        ipcRenderer.send('getSettings');
    
        return () => {
          ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners();
        };
      }, [])
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (settings != null) {
          setStartedUp(true);
        }
      }, [settings])
    
      function loadSettings(data) {
        console.log('loading settings...')
        if (data != null) {
          setSettings(data);
          console.log('settings loaded: ', data)
        }
      }
    
     return (
        <>
          {startedUp ?
            <div className='content'>
              Content
            </div>
            :
            <div className='empty'>
              </div>}
        </>
      );
    };
    
    export default Home;
```

As stated above, sometimes when I relaunch the App a couple of times it works fine but most of the time it doesn't. I'm sure that I'm missing something fundamental here but I cant wrap my head around.

Hope somebody is able to help. Cheers!

Comment: Try with `handle`/`invoke` instead of `on`/`send`

Comment: It didn’t do the trick, however I removed the [] brackets from the useEffect and now it seems to work. Apparently the component rerendered before it could receive the settings and the listener was already removed. This took me way too long to figure out…

Comment: Do you understand what it means if you remove the dependency array? `getSettings` will be called on every render.

Comment: Yes I do understand. I only put the listener into a useEffect without dependency array since it should always be able to read if a setting has changed since I call that elsewhere as well.